# Are spam and offensive reputation penalties shown to the affected user?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, spam, offensive

Penalties for a valid spam/offensive flag are not displayed in a user's reputation history as shown to the public (I think that's a good idea). They are visible to moderators. Are they shown to the affected user?

Comment: Come to think of it, are they shown if the user ticks “show removed posts”? This may well have been a PEBKAC from the user (the post with the penalty was removed, obviously).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All users already see this in their own profile.  It's important to note that when a post is flagged a spam it's **deleted**, so they need to check the "show removed posts" checkbox for these entries to show up.