# Chart mouseover shows more rep than I have at edge

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

The chart at the edge is showing me a mouseover popup with more rep than I actually have. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> didn't catch the mouse pointer, so I drew in one by hand. I presume this affects all Stack Exchange sites.

[image]

Comment: Did you lose a bunch of rep recently?

Comment: Downvotes. The reputation you lose from downvoting answers is not taken into account in that graph. There is a dupe, looking for it now.

Comment: I have surely downvoted more than 100 times - and now it is showing 51562, a number that is also inaccurate.

Comment: Downvoting questions cost no rep. Sure you downvoted more than 100 answers?

Comment: I would think so, but I could be mistaken.